# The summary of my custom extension helper is not showed

Tags: asp.net

I created my custom Ajax.ActionLink helper (see below). I also write a summary above my code but it is not showed as it should be.

Here is what I see:

[image]

Here is an example of how it should appear:

[image]

**1st question:** As you can see, the summary is not used. Any idea?

**2nd question:** Usually the summary (when minimized) should appears like this:

[image]

But mine appears like this:

[image]

Any idea?

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns an anchor element that contains the URL to the specified action method;
    //     when the action link is clicked, the action method is invoked asynchronously
    //     by using JavaScript.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   ajaxHelper:
    //     The AJAX helper.
    //
    //   actionName:
    //     The name of the action method.
    //
    //   routeValues:
    //     An object that contains the parameters for a route. The parameters are retrieved
    //     through reflection by examining the properties of the object. This object
    //     is typically created by using object initializer syntax.
    //
    //   ajaxOptions:
    //     An object that provides options for the asynchronous request.
    //
    //   htmlAttributes:
    //     An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An anchor element.
    public static IHtmlString ActionLink(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string actionName, object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        // Allow to have an ActionLink without any text link >> used for buttons with icon only
        return ajaxHelper.ActionLink(
            " ",
            actionName,                
            routeValues,
            ajaxOptions,
            htmlAttributes
        );
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look like a Valid [`XML Document Comment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx).

It should be in the Form

```
/// <summary>
///     Returns an anchor element that contains the URL to the specified action method;
///     when the action link is clicked, the action method is invoked asynchronously
///     by using JavaScript.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ajaxHelper">The AJAX helper.</param>
/// <returns>An anchor element</returns>
```

Comment: You are right, but even if I correct it, when the summary is minimized (click on the + sign on the left in the code window) it is not showed as intended (see my question 2). Any idea?

Comment: You have a leading `//` on the line before. try remove that.

Comment: Yes I removed this leading // but when minimized I still have /// <summary> ... (on a signel line) and I would like ... (on the left of the declaration of the method). Is it possible?

Comment: Can you put you're entire file online somewhere. It's impossible to guess what the issue is without seeing it, but I'm guessing there's some character in there that's breaking the XMLDoc.

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is possible. At least anytime I've ever used doc comments that's how it appears. `/// <summary>`

Comment: No matter. Thanks for your time. I'll mark this as solved at least for the 1st question.